# "He went ill and came back healthy" is it correct

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

I heard a man say:

> He went **ill** and came back **healthy**.

Here **ill** and **healthy** are *adjectives* and qualify the *subject,* **he.**

And the sentence structure is:

> **sub + verb + adjective**

Is it grammatically correct and how native speakers express this?

Thank you.

Comment: It's correct. But I would not say those adjectives function as complements. I would say they are predicative adjuncts.

Comment: To sound natural, it should really be *he **left** ill and came back healthy*. The phrase ***went*** *ill* is generally used to mean ***became*** *ill*. We might say *he took a bite and went ill*, meaning that he took a bite, became nauseated, and threw up.

Comment: Was the man saying the person physically moved/traveled, and that he was sick when he left but then healthy when he came back? Or, is the man just trying to say the person _got sick_ and then _recovered_?

Comment: @TypeIA actually the person physically traveled.

Answer (score 1):

It means "When he went he was ill. When he came back, he was healthy".

Grammatically the word ill is an adjective.  It describes the subject. This is not a very common expression.

There is some ambiguity. The phrase "go ill" also means "become ill". I don't think this is the meaning here because "come back healthy" doesn't mean "become healthy".  So "go" has its usual meaning of "travel (to some place)". He physically moved. This is the most natural reading given the (lack of) context.